# Can't get static URL to work in CSS

Tags: css, django

I'm having trouble adding a static file to my CSS to use it as a background image for my site. The static url does work because I've tested it in the HTML ,but for some reason it doesn't work in the CSS.

HTML:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}
    <div class ='splash'>
        <a href="{{ STATIC_URL }}background.JPG"> try me </a>
        </div>

{% endblock body %}
```

CSS:

```
    .splash{
    background-image: url("{{ STATIC_URL }}background.JPG");

    background-size: 100%;
    height: 1000px;


    }
```

DOES NOT WORK

```
TEST CSS:

.splash{
    background-image: url("http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/background.JPG");

    background-size: 100%;
    height: 1000px;


}
```

DOES WORK

..any ideas how make the static URL work?

Comment: If your CSS is in a separate file `{{ STATIC_URL}}` is not going to work as your CSS files aren't being rendered by Django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django won't process the css file. In a production server, it is likely to be just served by nginx or apache for example.

Use relative path instead.

If your css file is on the same dir as your background image, just put it like this:

```
.splash {
    background-image: url("background.JPG");
}
```

Or you may use the full url:

```
.splash {
    background-image: url("/static/background.JPG");
}
```

If you have a dir structure like this:

```
|static
|--css
|--img
```

You can specify it like this:

```
.splash {
    background-image: url("../img/background.JPG");
}
```

Comment: Thanks man.. I saw the other examples use the static url but I guess it might of been in the HTML.